# algorithm for synchronization of attributes in records

Tags: algorithm

We have a different records stored in different objects.
Let's say there are 8 objects and each objects has some records which are unique to that object.
Each object contains a million record which have a attribute that can be changed. Now after some time we are trying to sync all the records.
Initial approach:
Take a lock on each object separately(one at a time so that requests coming can be processed by reading the records in other objects) and sync the records inside it.

Is there any other approach so that we can maximize the request processing and less time on object locking?

Comment: maybe you can track the changes on the object? If so, you only have to check the changes..

Answer (score 0):

So if the records can be `sort()` in any way, i.e. the set of the records is a partially ordered set, then the set can be organized in a BST(`Binary Search Tree`), which takes `O(log)` to find an item with a specified key.

Thus, for every record in an object, find it in all the other objects, and then update it.

You have N(N=8) objects and each has M(M=1,000,000) records in it. The whole algorithm takes `O(N*N*M*Log(M))` which is surely acceptable.

Btw, if all the stuffs are in a database, just enumerate and update.

Comment: We don't have to sync records in different objects records which are there in each objects are unique.
The main purpose of asking is, is there any way through we can reduce the time of locking on the objects or through which we can process some critical  requests without delay.

Comment: I mean the whole process can be done in quarters, so you can just lock them when you adapt changes. If not so, sorry i don't know